# Java FX2.0 Table View

Tags: javafx

Table view is not resizing when window maximizes.there any properly for this ?
Is used the table as log viewer in my  project,i need it to be occupying the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code for a table which will resize to occupy all available space in a window, regardless of the window size, maximize state, etc.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableResize extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
      new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName")
    );
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
      new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName")
    );

    TableView table = new TableView();
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
      new Person("Ethan", "Williams")
    ));
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().add(table);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

    private Person(String fName, String lName) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
      this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); }
  }
}
```

The example is a modified version of the code from the [JavaFX TableView tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

Perhaps you are using a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) rather than an appropriate [resizable layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) as your root node.  Or perhaps you did not set an appropriate [column resize policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#columnResizePolicyProperty) on the table.  It is hard to say what your layout issue is without provided code, but hopefully you can get your code to work with the help of the above example.